# Fragment Spinner Not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

**Here is the Java Code**

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_create_report, container, false);
        activity = getActivity();


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerComplaintType);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterComplaint = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.complaintType);
        adapterComplaint.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterComplaint);

        spinnerComplaintType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                complaintType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), complaintType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }
```

**Here is the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="833dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="Complaint Type: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerComplaintType"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Vehicle Type"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerVehicleType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2" 
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerVehicleType"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Body No:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextBodyNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" >

       <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPlate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextBodyNo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextComplaintDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Plate No:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Date of Incident"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Complaint Details"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextPlate"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
        android:ems="10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPhotoReport"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonCamera"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/about" 
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="File Complaint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinnerVehicleType"

        android:text="Take Photo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextComplaintDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"

        android:text="SEND" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextComplaintDetails"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextComplaintDetails"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="pick date" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaintType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is the Error
**Log Trace**

```
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.CreateReportFragment.onCreateView(CreateReportFragment.java:31)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:830)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1034)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1384)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:428)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-04 21:18:36.513: E/AndroidRuntime(3772):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I was able to make a **Spinner** work in a single **Activity**, but when I transferred the code to a **Fragment** it obviously didn't work.

I think the Error was from the Instatiation of Spinner.

Comment: Good chance you need to clean your project. In eclipse: Project -> Clean, in AS: Build -> Rebuild project

Comment: Post your xml file here

Comment: At anywhere have you using TextView in your xml file?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes sir. i used some. i will post the whole xml.

Comment: SO there is problem while you are displaying your UI content in xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one for your ***TextView*** and ***Spinner***.

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerComplaintType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinnerComplaintType"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="File Complaint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Also Change

```
     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

instead of

```
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

in your Array Adapter.

UPDATE:

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.complaintType, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

Comment: Thanks! it works! but still it is not populated even i have already did the  **spinner.setAdapter(adapterComplaint);**

Comment: set your SPinner width match_parent

Comment: the spinner is still not populated. its not working.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie Have you checked this one?

Comment: Thank you! I hope you can help me with my other concerns in transforming my activity code to fragment :)

Comment: @AndroidNewbie Ya sure..Wel come!

Comment: will you invite me in a chat. to ask further more question?

Comment: Ya..Sure. But after weekend.